# read csv file into 2-d array in c

Tags: c, arrays, csv, output

I'm not familiar with C at all. I just need to input my data into an already well-developed model in C, put the data in arrays, get my output and put that output back into my program in Python. My data is in a CSV file and I'm just trying to put it in a 2-D array to run through some functions. When I run the following code to make sure I created my array, I get a random single value in the output that does not match the original data at all. Sometimes it prints 0.00000. I'm trying to view the entire array to make sure it's ready to be input.

Also, this is just a sample; my real data set will have >3000 rows. I understand I will need to use `malloc()` for this when I run my real data, correct?

@user3629249 thank you and @Cool Guy for all your comments. Here's what I have now. I think sprintf() is still having trouble converting my array values back to a float. I've searched all over and I still cant tell what I doing wrong but the error is telling me that data[l][k] and todata are still incompatible, could you tell me if I'm on the right track and what I'm doing wrong with the sprintf() function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("airvariablesSend.csv", "r");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("cannot open file\n\n");
    return -1;
}
```

// Headers removed for simplicity. Still found in airvariables.csv to see which //column means what

```
float data[9][6]; //for putting into array
int k , l;
float num; //for using getline() function
char *memory;
int nbytes = 500;
```

// space for using malloc? Is this enough or too much?

```
char *token; //for parsing through line using strtok()
char *search = ","; //delimiter for csv 
char *todata; //for
```

//asking for space on heap

```
memory = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
```

// Don;t need to use realloc() because getline() does it automatically? //http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/getline.html

```
for(k = 0; k < 6 ; k++) //repeats for max number of columns
{
    for (l=0; l< 9; l++) //modify for number of rows that you have
    {     
        num = getline (&memory, &nbytes, fp); //reading line by line
        token = strtok(num, search); //separating lines by comma in csv
```

//Apparently strtok() will only use whitespace and I'm getting warnings here too. Is there another function for separating by commas?

```
        sprintf(todata, "%f", token);
        data[l][k] = todata;
        printf("%f\n", data[l][k]); 
        }

        }
fclose(fp);
free(memory);



return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Oh right, yes I'm trying to skip over the 1st row because theyre headers (strings) but yes I'll change it back to 10, that's what I thought. I had it at l<10 before and I'm still getting the same outputs.

Comment: if the file fails to open, then the code should probably exit, not continue down and try reading from the file.  NOTGE: stdlib.h contains the exit() function and the #defines for EXIT_FAILURE and EXIT_SUCCESS

Comment: in C, array offsets begin with 0 and the highest valid offset is the number of array elements -1

Comment: there are several 'magic' numbers in the posted code.  suggest using #define for those number and using the #define'd name inplace of those magic numbers

Comment: for a large array, it is not a good idea to place it on the stack (like 'data' currently is)  rather use malloc() and realloc() to obtain room on the heap

Comment: in C, using fscanf() and the %f input/conversion operator, will not skip over a ','  It will skip over white space like tab, space, and newline.  so will fail to read beyond the first entry in the file.  Suggest: input the file line by line using getline() or fgets()  then parsing the line using strtok().  and extracting/converting each value using sprintf()

Comment: if you really want to skip over the first/header line, read it separately, first using getline() or fgets()

Comment: in the posted code, the whole file is being read into the data[][] array  then some printing is performed, then the program exits.  If the data is not to be kept, the there is no need to place the data into an array, just print each entry from the CSV file by replacing the assignment to data[][] = num with printf("%f\n", num);  WIth 3000+ rows and several values per row, that will result in a massive amount of lines being printed on a terminal.  Perhaps just read a whole row ruing fgets() and printing the whole row with printf()

Comment: Okay thank you @user3629249! These comments have been very helpful. I think I almost have it except I still have one error where I don't think my sprintf() function is converting the values of the array back to float. Could you tell me if this is better, and how I should change the sprintf()?

Comment: oh yeah, and @user3629249 I do need to keep the array because I need to input it into a complicated model that is already developed in c and then put the output the model gives me into my program in Python. The array I'm creating will be usable correct?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (l=1; l< 11; l++)
```

To

```
for (l=0; l< 10; l++)
```

And

```
printf("%f\n", data[10][7]);
```

To

```
printf("%f\n", data[l][k]);
```

And move the `printf` just after

```
data[l][k] = num;
```

The former is done because array indices start from 0 and end at length-1.
The latter is done because you need to loop through the array to get each value that is stored in each index of the array and print it. You can't just use `data[10][7]` and expect the whole array to be printed. `data[10][7]` is an invalid location and accessing it invokes Undefined Behavior which means that anything can happen including segmentation faults, runtime errors, crashes etc.

Also, add a `return -1;` in the end of the body of the first `if` to end the execution of the program if the `fopen` failed to open its first argument.